# Sending email notification on successful event

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

I am working on an Laravel 5.8 API application that need to notify users when they successfully place an order. The order process works but I am not getting the email notification. Here's how I am going about it using mailtrap for demo purpose

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=**************
MAIL_PASSWORD=**************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

In Order model I am using the notifiable trait

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\User;
use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;

    ...
}
```

Created the `OrderSuccesful` notification and using it in the `OrderController` store method like so

```
<?php

...

use App\Notifications\OrderSuccessful;

use App\Order;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class OrderController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request, Product $product)
    {
        // create order
        $order = Order::create([
            'user_id'       => auth()->user()->id,
            'product_id'    => $product->id,
            'barrels'       => $request->barrels,
            'status'        => 'successful'
        ]);

        $user = auth()->user();

        // notify user of successful order
        $user->notify(new OrderSuccessful($order));

        return new OrderResource($order);
    }
}
```

Now when I make a successful order, I don't get a notification. Since I am using the notification for the first time, I am wondering what I have missed. Appreciate it if someone can point that out and tell me how to fix it.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: No error is thrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you need to add the `Notifiable` trait to the `User` model instead of `Order`.

In `User.php`

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    //
}
```

Create a `OrderSuccessful` notification class using `artisan`:

`php artisan make:notification OrderSuccessful`

In `OrderSuccessful` class:

```php
protected $order;

public function __construct(App\Order $order)
{
    $this->order = $order;
}
```

Once everything mentioned above are setup, you should now be able to trigger emails using the following code:

`$user->notify(new OrderSuccessful($order));`

**NOTE:**

Make sure your `users` table have an `email` field with a proper email address in it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: All set but my users table has no email field. The email field is actually called username. Could this be the reason? How do I work with the username instead?

Comment: You need to define `routeNotificationForMail` on the `User` model and return `username` within that function.  More information about how to customize the recipient https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/notifications#mail-notifications

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped!